# Remove duplicates on click in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, duplicates

I have this.

```
var studentsList = [
    {"Id": "101", "name": "One"},
    {"Id": "101", "name": "One"},
    {"Id": "102", "name": "Two"},
    {"Id": "103", "name": "Three"},
    {"Id": "103", "name": "Three"},
    {"Id": "104", "name": "Four"},
    {"Id": "104", "name": "Four"}
];
```

I want to toggle, remove duplicates from this object on click.

```
<button ng-click="removeDuplicates = !removeDuplicates"></button>
```

How can I do this, any ideas?

Thank in advance :)

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: I just created 2 similar object , first one with duplicates , second one without (filtered) ,and hide/show (switch) them onclick. But its nor the best way i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.studentsList = [
    {"Id": "101", "name": "One"},
    {"Id": "101", "name": "One"},
    {"Id": "102", "name": "Two"},
    {"Id": "103", "name": "Three"},
    {"Id": "103", "name": "Three"},
    {"Id": "104", "name": "Four"},
    {"Id": "104", "name": "Four"}
];
}]).filter('dupfilter',function(){
  var cache = {};
  return function(array, dup){
    if(dup)
      return array;
      
    var key = JSON.stringify(array);
    if(cache[key])  
      return cache[key];
    
    var temp = [];
    for(var item of array){
      item.$$hashKey = undefined;
      var str = JSON.stringify(item);
      if(temp.indexOf(str) == -1)
        temp.push(str);
    }
    var result = [];
    for(var item of temp)
      result.push(JSON.parse(item));
      
    cache[key] = result;
      
    return result;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyController">    
   <input type='button' value='{{(removeDuplicates ? "Allow" : "Remove") + " duplicates"}}' ng-click='removeDuplicates=!removeDuplicates'/>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat='item in studentsList | dupfilter: !removeDuplicates'>{{item | json}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir :) You save my week )

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function which will remove the duplicate from a Array based on any key(in r case its name).
pass your studentsList in "originalArray" and name in "prop".

```
removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
    var newArray = [];
    var lookupObject  = {};

    for(var i in originalArray) {
        lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
    }

    for(i in lookupObject) {
        newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```